# Export to Html fails if cursor is right behind the text in EditText

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` into which I simply type one word: Test. I leave the cursor where it is (directly behind the word). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Then I simply call `Html.toHtml(...)` on that `EditText`:

```
String text = Html.toHtml(mEditText.getText());
```

The result is:

```
<p dir="ltr"><u>Test</u></p>
```

Where do the tags `<u>...</u>` come from? It seems that the call `toHtml` interpretes the underlining of the cursor as a text formatting. I don't want to have the tags `<u>...</u>` in my exported html just because the cursor was at the end of the text. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: String text = Html.toHtml(mEditText.getText()).replace("<u>", "").replace("</u>", "");

Comment: If the user can format the text, then this solution is not doable.